# how to understand the logic of null distribution

Tags: f-distribution

In a statistics textbook I read the following about comparing two population variances by using independent samples:

If a null hypothesis (stating that the ratio of two population variances is 1) is true, then the sampling distribution of ratios of sample variances is an F distribution.

How can we know that the hypothesis is true if a sampling distribution is not known?

Comment: The F-distribution you mention is correct only if both samples are taken randomly from normal distributions.

Comment: Ok but how can you test a hypothesis without having a sampling distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These types of tests are based on "proof by contradiction" where we assume the opposite of what we want to prove is true, then try to find a contradiction (low p-value in this case) to disprove the null case giving evidence for the alternative.

So we start by assuming that the null hypothesis is true (and usually some other assumptions) and use the sampling distribution based on that assumption.

In the case of comparing 2 variances, if the 2 populations have the same variance (ratio of variances is 1) and the populations are normally distributed, the samples are random, etc. then the sampling distribution will be an F-distribution and we can do the calculations based on that.  A small p-value indicates that either our assumption about the variances being equal (or another assumption) is false, or by random chance we saw something that was very unlikely to happen by chance.  The standard approach is then to conclude that the assumption of interest (equal variances) is false.  We do not need to know the sampling distribution under other conditions, this is sufficient for this type of test (for rejecting).

Note that a large p-value does **not** prove the assumption to be true.  We can not prove the variances are exactly equal unless we have all of the data on the entire populations.

With other techniques we may be able to show that they are similar enough that we don't care about any differences, but that is beyond what the book is talking about.